# How to rewrite for-each loop into stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a data structure named "Book" that consists of the following fields:

```
public final class Book {
    private final String title;
    private final BookType bookType;
    private final List<Author> authors;
}
```

My goal is to derive a `Map<Author, List<BookType>>` from a `List<Book>`using Stream API.

To achieve it, at first, I've made a for-each loop to clarify the steps of the solution and after I've rewritten it into streams based approach step-by-step:

```
Map<Author, List<BookType>> authorListBookType = new HashMap<>();
books.stream().forEach(b -> b.getAuthors().stream().forEach(e -> {
     if (authorListBookType.containsKey(e)) {
        authorListBookType.get(e).add(b.getBookType());
     }  else {
        authorListBookType.put(e, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(b.getBookType())));
     }
}));
```

But it isn't a Stream API based solution and I've gotten in stuck and I don't know how to finish it properly.
I know that I must use grouping collector to obtain the required `Map<Author, List<BookType>>` straight from streams.

Could you give me some hints, please?

Comment: Why do you need a stream solution? Standard loops are often easier to read and are, in the vast majority of cases, faster.

Comment: @Bohemian My sentiments as well. Streams are cool and all, and are great for some use cases, but trying to shoehorn them into every solution is a mistake.. They are a tool, not a requirement.

Comment: I need it to practice streams

Comment: Apart from practicing streams, check out `Map`'s `computeIfAbsent() ` which would replace the `if-then`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pair each author of each book with its book type, then collect:

```
Map<Author, Set<BookType>> authorListBookType = books.stream()
    .flatMap(book -> book.getAuthors().stream()
            .map(author -> Map.entry(author, book.getType())))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.toSet())));
```

Here I've used Java 9's `Map.entry(key, value)` to create the pairs, but you can use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value)` or any other `Pair` class at your disposal.

This solution uses [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to create the desired `Map` instance.

As @Bohemian points out in the comments, you need to collect to a `Set` instead of a `List` to avoid duplicates.

---

However, I find the stream-based solution a little bit convoluted, because when you pair authors and book types in `Map.Entry` instances, you then have to use `Map.Entry` methods in the `Collectors.groupingBy` part, thus losing the initial semantics of your solution, as well as some readability...

So here's another solution:

```
Map<Author, Set<BookType>> authorListBookType = new HashMap<>();
books.forEach(book -> 
    book.getAuthors().forEach(author ->
            authorListBookType.computeIfAbsent(author, k -> new HashSet<>())
        .add(book.getType())));
```

Both solutions assume `Author` implements `hashCode` and `equals` consistently.

Comment: Is there`Collectors.mapping()` with single arugment?

Comment: Agreed, but you probably want to dedupe the booktype list as you’ll get lots of dupes (most authors write in one type). Really, the result should probably be `Map<Author, Set<BookType>>`

Answer (score 3):

I'll be looking for a more efficient solution but, in the meantime, here's a working (but inefficient) solution:

```
books.stream()
     .map(Book::getAuthors)
     .flatMap(List::stream)
     .distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), author -> {
         return books.stream().filter(book -> book.getAuthors().contains(author))
                              .map(Book::getBookType).collect(Collectors.toList());
      }));
```

I definitely prefer the non-stream solution though.  One optimization is to change `List<Author>` to `Set<Author>` (as I assume the same author wouldn't be listed twice); searching will be improved, but the solution is still slower than your for-loop due to the stream overhead.

**Note**: This assumes that you've correctly implemented `Author#equals` and `Author#hashCode`.

Comment: Do you mean that `list` is `books`?

Comment: @saka1029 My bad, forgot to replace my test code with `books`.

Comment: Your answer returns `Map<Author, List<Book>>` instead of `Map<Author, List<BookType>>`

Comment: @saka1029 I must be dyslexic, I could have sworn I had read `List<Book>`.  Anyway, I'll change it!  Edit: Just changed it, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a little bit similar to @Federico's in the sense that the mapping is the same (+1). The motivation for this answer was to try and solve the problem at hand as well as making it as readable as possible.

First, we need to create a function to hide the logic for the mapping:

```
private static Stream<? extends AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Author, BookType>> mapToEntry(Book book) {
        return book.getAuthors().stream()
                .map(author -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(author, book.getBookType()));
}
```

Second, we need to create a function for the merging logic:

```
private static List<BookType> merge(List<BookType> left, List<BookType> right) {
        left.addAll(right);
        return left;
}
```

Third, we need to create a function for the valueMapper:

```
private static List<BookType> valueMapper(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Author, BookType> entry){
        return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Now, one can do:

```
Map<Author, List<BookType>> resultSet =
                books.stream()
                     .flatMap(Main::mapToEntry)
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                            Main::valueMapper,
                                 Main::merge));
```

Where `Main` represents the class containing the `mapToEntry`, `valueMapper` and `merge` functions.

- `Main::mapToEntry` maps books to `SimpleEntry`'s containing the author and the book type which `flatMap` then collapses it to a `Stream<? extends AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Author, BookType>>`
- `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey` is a mapping function to produce
  the map keys.
- `Main::valueMapper` is a mapping function to produce values of the
  map.
- `Main::merge` is a merge function, used to resolve collisions between
  values associated with the same key.

The benefit I can see from this is that we isolate the mapping logic, merging etc. away from the stream methods, this comes with better readability and easier to maintain as if you want to further apply more complex logic on the stream pipeline, you only have to look at the methods and modify those and not touch the stream pipeline at all.